# how to perform Two select query in one stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to perform two select query in one stored procedure. But its not giving me any output. There is no error but records are not being displayed.

First I tried this stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_PriceList_Die_Wise]
@DieNo As Nvarchar(15),
@MetalCode As Int
AS
BEGIN
Select CP.BatchQty,CP.CastingPrice,U.UNITName As 'Unit',MachPrice,U.UNITName As 'M/C Unit' from CustomerPriceList As CP Left Outer Join UNITMaster As U On CP.MUNITID=U.UNITID where MOULDCODE=@DieNo And METALCODE=@MetalCode

SELECT TOP (10) SubOADetail.OANO, SubOADetail.ID, SubOADetail.QTY, SubOADetail.RATE, UNITMaster.UNITName As Unit, OATest.MachPrices, UNITMaster_1.UNITName AS Unit FROM UNITMaster AS UNITMaster_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN OATest ON UNITMaster_1.UNITID = OATest.MachUnitID RIGHT OUTER JOIN SubOADetail LEFT OUTER JOIN UNITMaster ON SubOADetail.UNIT = UNITMaster.UNITID ON OATest.ID = SubOADetail.ID AND OATest.OANO = SubOADetail.OANO LEFT OUTER JOIN OADetails ON SubOADetail.OANO = OADetails.OANO WHERE SubOADetail.MOULDCODE = @DieNo AND SubOADetail.METALCODE =@MetalCode  ORDER BY OADetails.OADATE DESC
END
```

This gives me output like this

[image: This is my output Image]

but I want the output in single table so I created this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_PriceList_Die_Wise]
@DieNo As Nvarchar(15),
@MetalCode As Int
AS
BEGIN
WITH main AS 
(
  Select CP.BatchQty,CP.CastingPrice,U.UNITName As 'Unit',
  MachPrice,U.UNITName As 'M/C Unit' from CustomerPriceList As CP 
  Left Outer Join UNITMaster As U On CP.MUNITID=U.UNITID 
  where MOULDCODE=@DieNo And METALCODE=@MetalCode
), sub AS
(
  SELECT TOP (10) SubOADetail.OANO, SubOADetail.ID, SubOADetail.QTY, SubOADetail.RATE, 
  UNITMaster.UNITName As Unit, OATest.MachPrices, UNITMaster_1.UNITName AS MCUnit 
  FROM UNITMaster AS UNITMaster_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN OATest ON UNITMaster_1.UNITID = OATest.MachUnitID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN SubOADetail LEFT OUTER JOIN UNITMaster ON SubOADetail.UNIT = UNITMaster.UNITID 
  ON OATest.ID = SubOADetail.ID AND OATest.OANO = SubOADetail.OANO LEFT OUTER JOIN OADetails 
  ON SubOADetail.OANO = OADetails.OANO WHERE SubOADetail.MOULDCODE = @DieNo 
  AND SubOADetail.METALCODE =@MetalCode  ORDER BY OADetails.OADATE DESC
)
SELECT * 
  FROM main m join sub s
    ON m.MachPrice = s.MachPrices
END
```

But this gives me blank record like this

[image: I want record in this output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `INNER JOIN`, and your first table (main) don't have any records, so you will not get any output.

If you want to select from other table even if matching records are not there in the main, you need to change your `JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN` like following.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM main m right join sub s
    ON m.MachPrice = s.MachPrices
```

EDIT:

`RIGHT JOIN` will work for the provided sample data, in case if you have data where left CTE don't have matching records in right CTE or vise versa and you still want to select the records, for such scenario you need a combination of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, for this you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` like following.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM main m full outer join sub s
    ON m.MachPrice = s.MachPrices
```

Comment: If main is empty, shouldn't this be a right join, or rather sub first and a left join to main?

Comment: @SQL_M, you are right, i didn't realized while writing. I will update it now.

Comment: If first table(main) have records than it will work perfectly.?

Comment: for that we have to write "FULL OUTER JOIN" in place of "RIGHT JOIN"

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN Is combination of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN.. I am not aware of the data.. if any of the table cant have data in that case you should use FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: @CompanyCompany, i have edited the answer for FULL OUTER JOIN.